# How difficult is it to construct the time inverse of a state?

Tags: quantum-information, time, information

This is a vague question, but I hope it can have some sort of answer. Given an isolated state, classical or quantum, of finite size, how difficult is it to actually produce a state that is the time-reverse of the first state, to within some reasonable margin of error?

Comment: This is too broad. Are you taking about an open system or a closed system? Give context.

Comment: Optical phase conjugation will do this for you in certain simple cases.

Comment: Broad was sort of the point, I was wondering if there were *any* results on this.  Closed systems, for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Maybe the idea of Nielsen on the quantum computation complexity on Riemannian manifold can help. Generally this is difficult.